# SWT: No more handles in Eclipse Luna win8.1

Tags: eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I have a HP PC with Windows 8.1, with 2 monitors and I use Eclipse Luna with SWT. I develop a tool that has a dialog with 3 composites (one with a table, one with buttons on it, and one with labels and a progress bar). I wrote it because I haven't had this problem until I changed the absolute layout with formLayouts. Now if I click to designer tab in Window Builder, I get the following popup:

[image: No more handles]

(Details>> shows the exact same message)

When click to OK, it says: WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI.

WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error.

And the Stack trace is:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [GetLastError=0x57]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.init(Image.java:1583)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:180)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShot(OSSupportWin32.java:118)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShotsHierarchy(OSSupportWin32.java:101)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShotsHierarchy(OSSupportWin32.java:106)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShotsHierarchy(OSSupportWin32.java:106)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShotsHierarchy(OSSupportWin32.java:106)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.os.win32.OSSupportWin32.makeShots(OSSupportWin32.java:66)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.rcp.support.ToolkitSupportImpl.makeShots(ToolkitSupportImpl.java:63)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swt.support.ToolkitSupport.makeShots(ToolkitSupport.java:59)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swt.model.widgets.ControlInfo.createShotImages(ControlInfo.java:256)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swt.model.widgets.ControlInfo.refresh_fetch(ControlInfo.java:182)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swt.model.widgets.ControlInfo.refresh_fetch(ControlInfo.java:157)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.rcp.model.jface.WindowInfo.refresh_fetch(WindowInfo.java:218)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo$6$1.run(ObjectInfo.java:496)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:145)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo$6.run(ObjectInfo.java:494)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo.execRefreshOperation(ObjectInfo.java:514)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo.refresh(ObjectInfo.java:492)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:580)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:527)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:263)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:241)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3110)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1794)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:283)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

The program is running correct, and I didn't noticed any problem with the GUI at runtime.

I looked for this problem, but all answers I found haven't worked for me (checked processes, drivers, other software etc.) Hope I didn't forget  to wrote any related information.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed by turning off "nVidia Desktop Manager".

Other people fixed the problem by turning off other DeskTop manager apps like "DisplayFussion".